# If post date is older than 30 days, then ...

Tags: php, date

I want to post news on my website but I want them to disappear whenever the date of post (lets say $date) is older than 30 days.

$date will be displayed as numbers, zo 5384054354

Can anyone help? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "disappear"?  Deleted from the database?  Hidden from pages?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explained what that number is. A unix timestamp? It's far too big to be a 32bit timestamp.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more info Chloe. You haven't mentioned a database or anything. How are these posts stored?

Comment: @MarcB: It's Friday 12th August 2140 10:39:14 AM UTC.

Comment: @mark: in which case I don't think answering this question is time critical, since posts won't be getting '30 days old' for another 128 years anyways. On the other hand, maybe this is a blog with future technology details...

Comment: @Mark - what format is the timestamp in?

Comment: @andrewsi: That was assuming it was indeed a unixstamp (just a large one). I really have no idea. I think OP just mashed her keyboard for an example.

Comment: @Mark - Ah - I was wondering if it was a format I'd not seen before.

Comment: I think the great question here is "what does desapear mean"? If it is a simple "do not display" request, you just have to tell it in your SQL request. I will post such a request if you valid the idea it is only a "do not display" request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them not to appear in your results from the query, use something like this:

```
select 
    col1, 
    col2 
from 
    yourTable 
where 
    dateColumn>date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
    and ... // Any other criteria you use.
```

You can use a similar query once in a while to delete records if you want to delete them from the database entirely (though this might be something you regret later)